# apt update failed to fetch

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, update-manager

I'm having an issue when running the command "sudo apt update" in Ubuntu 22.04, some repos give me the warning failed to fetch. Been trying for some days now, and keep getting the same error, here the output of the command:

```
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                             
Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                   
Hit:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release                           
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                  
Hit:10 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                        
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Ign:11 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:12 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:11 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:12 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:11 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:12 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:11 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Err:12 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've been looking for another similar question, but haven't found this specific warningfor this ubuntu version.

Comment: The host `http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` works for me, at this moment.

Comment: If you get regular issues on that *mirror*, you could always switch to the main archive (*remove the ar. from your URLs*) or choose another mirror - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Thank you so much! That absolutely solved my problem ️